# Am I supposed to code a different Gulp file for every project?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I mean – I usually need the same Gulp configuration, the same functions, the same plugins (sass into css compilation, minifying JavaScript, etc.). Do I have to code a new `gulpfile.js` every time I start a new project? Or is it any way to just deploy my usual Gulp configuration in my new project? Or did I totally misunderstand Gulp?

Comment: Can't you just copy the file from a previous project?

Comment: Yes, sure I can, but I was hoping there was a more natural, optimised, automatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/); you can install various *generators* for the different types of project that you may want to build. Many of the generators will walk you through creating a new project, what frameworks you'd like to install etc, plus often generate a gulpfile or gruntfile automatically. If you find yourself starting a lot of projects with the same boilerplate then it is worth having a look at.

Here's a generator for a gulp powered webapp: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp